# Saving HTML page to MySQL Database and then inserting code into that HTML and seeving it up again

Tags: php, mysql, html

I'm trying to build something similar to the "Try on your site" on http://www.mywebpresenters.com/

I want to let users enter in their URL, then I need to save the HTML of that URL/Page to a MySQL database using PHP. I then need to insert a div containing more code and then serve up the whole lot to the user again.

I have done this using an IFrame but I'd like to do it better.

Can anyone shed light on this? Also, This will be used on a WordPress site if that adds in anyway.

Thanks in advance,

Barry

Comment: `using an iframe`... what do you mean? currently you are adding an `<iframe>` but would prefer to us a `<div>`?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to save the whole html page in the database use the smarty. It simply fetch a html file in a variable like

```
$myvar  = smarty->fetch('htmlfile');
```

now you can simply save the `$myvar` into the sql.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are prepared to parse the HTML and remove the head/body tags of the scraped page, than an iFrame is the way to go.  You could probably use a find/replace algorithm when you retrieve the stored HTML from the server to insert the containing code that you need into the correct location.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I could personally think of doing this is having them upload the page to your site and then doing a mysql query using PHP to store it into database. Then using the PHP 5 DomDocument model to take that same code and save it as a dynamic page.

Well actually, you can do it two ways. You can use PHP cURL library to get the url of the page and simply parse and save the HTML code to the database as well.

To present it in a div you want to use javascript and get the div a target _top attribute so window.open can load the content in that page.

You don't even need WordPress for this to be honest. This can be done by scratch.